# How to dynamically remove records from a table via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table that is dynamically created.

The following jQuery code captures the tr that the user has selected in that table, and populates another table called "selected_users" with specific data from the row that's been picked.

```
$('#available_users tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var tr;
    tr=$('<tr/>');

    var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
    if ( index === -1 ) {
        selected.push( id );

        var tds = $(this).find('td');
        tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(1).text() + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(3).text() + "</td>");
        $('#selected_users').append(tr);
    } else {
        selected.splice( index, 1 );
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
} );
```

**Question**

This logic is working.  But now what I need to do is when users deselect a previously selected record from the available_users table, I need to remove it from the "selected_users" table.

**What I've tried So far:**

The first thing I tried to do is to assign an ID to the `<TR>` that I create in the "selected_users" table, so that I can use this id to find the row I want to delete.
I tried to change my code to look like this:

```
    var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
    if ( index === -1 ) {
        selected.push( id );

        var tds = $(this).find('td');
        tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(1).text() + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + tds.eq(3).text() + "</td>");
        tr.attr('id') = id.substring(4);  //******* NEW ********
        $('#selected_users').append(tr);
```

But it bombs with an error "ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side".
The other question is how to remove the  from the selected_users table.  I'd like to put the logic in the else path ...

```
    } else {
        selected.splice( index, 1 );
         //*** add logic to remove also from the selected_users table.
    }
```

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

All the code I've posted here works, except the attempt to dynamically assign the ID attribute to the new `<TR>` I'm adding.  I think in this case, all the details might be making things more complicated ???

Maybe it would simplify things if I just asked how do so something like this:

```
var tr;
tr.append("<td>value1</td>");
$('#test_table').append(tr);
```

When doing something like the above, how would you assign an id of "id=123" to the `<tr>`?

Also, if you only had the row id (`<tr id=123>`), how could you delete the entire row from test_table?

Comment: Could you supply a complete demo on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: @sємsєм https://jsfiddle.net/hh4xx6ah/

Comment: The code does not work.

Comment: Try `tr.attr('id', id.substring(4)) ; `

Comment: What is the full path to your file at `cgi-bin/users` and can it be accessed from another domain so we can test?

Comment: `cgi-bin/users` path for javascript & html? hmmmh... sound fishy. @Happydevdays please don't fall for that.

Comment: @DelightedD0D sorry, it's an internal site.

Comment: @sємsєм what do you think about my EDIT 2?  I've tried to boil the questions down to simpler examples...

Comment: Very good edit you have done @Happydevdays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm assuming that this is the line that "*bombs with an error `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`*":

```
tr.attr('id') = id.substring(4);
```

I make this assumption because `attr('id')` will return a String, which is immutable, and you're trying to assign a new String (of `id.substring(4)`) to that existing string.

If you wish to set a new value to the `id` you need to use the *setter* form of the `attr()` method:

```
tr.attr('id', id.substring(4))`
```

Or, assuming the substring is to be taken from the current `id`:

```
tr.attr('id', function (index, currentProperyValue) {
    return currentPropertyValue.substring(4);
});
```

In the above the argument-names are user-defined, the first argument (above: 'index') is the index of the current element returned by the collection in the `tr` variable; the second (above: 'currentPropertyValue') represents the current-value of the property we're changing with the method.

> …if you only had the row id (`<tr id=123>`), how could you delete the entire row from test_table?

Simply, using jQuery:

```
$('#123').remove();
```

Which will remove the element from the document (wherever that element appears within the document, bearing in mind that duplicate `id`s are invalid, so if two elements occur with that same `id` only the *first element with that `id`* will be removed).

Alternatively, but still simply, using plain JavaScript; here we're using a variable because we need to get the same element twice:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('123');

elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
  - [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
  - [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/).
  - [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped :)